# Multi criteria dlookup issue

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have spent some time working this Dlookup but to no avail.

Looked online and as far as I am aware this is right.

```
= DLookUp("F5","tbl_Backlog","[F30]="N" AND [F9]='" & [Form]![Text166] & "'")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your criteria section looks to be incorrect.

```
= DLookUp("[F5]","tbl_Backlog","[F30]='N' AND [F9]='" & [Form]![Text166] & "'")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - Would it be the [Forms] area? Missing the form name?

Comment: Can I suggest you bookmark this page http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm it will assist you with all types of references to other things on forms.

Comment: I'm also very wary of any design that has field names such as F9 , F30 and controls like Text166....  Give things meaningful names a) it will help you, b)  it helps identify obvious errors. e.g. If F9 is in fact OrderLineID then it's likely to be a number and you are checking for a string.

Comment: @dmorgan20 Yes, `[Form]` would need to be replaced with your form's name.